# Почему не работает параллакс?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Почему не работает параллакс эффект ?

```js
var scrollParal = $(this).scrollTop();
console.log(scrollParal);


$('.middle .circle').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0%, ' + scrollParal + '%)'
});
```

```css
.top {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
}

.middle {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  background: url(https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/d/63/foto-kartinka-art-stil-domo.jpg);
}
.middle .circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background: green;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
footer {
   position: relative;
   height: 500px;
   background: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="top">
  Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Не лучше путь мир всеми назад над города приставка вскоре прямо текстов запятой собрал предложения, даль. От всех агенство, за обеспечивает.
</section>

<section class="middle">
  <span class="circle"></span>
</section>

<footer>
  
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы событие не задали, вот я изменил, но как то не понимаю что вы хотите сделать? Если объясните в вопросе то изменю ответ.

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
  var scrollParal = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('.middle .circle').css({
    'transform' : 'translate(0%, ' + scrollParal + '%)'
  });
});
```

```css
.top {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
}

.middle {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  background: url(https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/d/63/foto-kartinka-art-stil-domo.jpg);
}
.middle .circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background: green;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
footer {
   position: relative;
   height: 500px;
   background: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="top">
  Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Не лучше путь мир всеми назад над города приставка вскоре прямо текстов запятой собрал предложения, даль. От всех агенство, за обеспечивает.
</section>

<section class="middle">
  <span class="circle"></span>
</section>

<footer>
  
</footer>
```

Вот пример второй:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var middle_offset = $( ".middle" ).offset();
  var middle_top = middle_offset.top;
  console.log(middle_top);
  $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    var scrollParal = $(this).scrollTop() / 2;
    if(middle_top < $(this).scrollTop()){
      $('.middle .circle').css({
        'transform' : 'translate(0%, ' + scrollParal + '%)'
      });
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
.top {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
}

.middle {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  background: url(https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/d/63/foto-kartinka-art-stil-domo.jpg);
}
.middle .circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background: green;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
footer {
   position: relative;
   height: 500px;
   background: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="top">
  Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Не лучше путь мир всеми назад над города приставка вскоре прямо текстов запятой собрал предложения, даль. От всех агенство, за обеспечивает.
  
</section>
<section class="middle">
  
  <span class="circle"></span>
</section>

<footer>
  
</footer>
```

Comment: Вообще хочу круг параллаксом сделать, читал, что когда несколько секций нужно через ofsset высчитывать как-то и тогда круг в пределах секции будет плавно ездить не уезжая за пределы. Начал делать обычный паралакс и застопорился :(

Comment: Вы просто опишите хоть и картинками, и подробно, (грамотно) то что хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: Вот смотрите, такой же параллакс хочу сделать, но только во второй секции, но если сейчас менять, то он будет выезжать, поэтому и нужно как-то через offset, но я не знаю как это реализовать https://jsfiddle.net/0b3o45qg/21/

Comment: @YourDeveloper какая вторая секция? по классу хоть скажите

Comment: Которая middle,  я хочу сделать тоже самое с кругом, что сейчас на jsfiddle, но только в секции middle

Answer (score 1):

```js
var scrollParal;
window.onscroll = function() {
scrollParal = $(window).scrollTop();

$('.middle .circle').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0%, ' + scrollParal/5 + 'px)'
});
}
```

```css
.top {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
}

.middle {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  background: url(https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/d/63/foto-kartinka-art-stil-domo.jpg);
}
.middle .circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background: green;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
footer {
   position: relative;
   height: 500px;
   background: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="top">
  Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Не лучше путь мир всеми назад над города приставка вскоре прямо текстов запятой собрал предложения, даль. От всех агенство, за обеспечивает.
</section>

<section class="middle">
  <span class="circle"></span>
</section>

<footer>
  
</footer>
```

Comment: Спасибо, решение вполне подходит. Но как его сделать универсальным ? Получается если на сайте будет 10 секций, то нужно будет scrollParal делить на x, а x экспериментальным путем выискивать . Как-нибудь можно сделать, чтоб отсчет был в пределах секции. Чтоб не общий скролл делился на 5, а просто скролл секции создавал паралакс ?