# Параллакс страницы

Tags: html, css

Как создать параллакс эффект, чтобы фоновое изображение прокручивалось медленно, в то время как блоки страницы (прозрачные) перемещались быстрее?
Эффект увидел на [ЭТОЙ](https://www.sst.moscow/master-klassy) странице. Не сочтите за рекламу, точнее не знаю как объяснить, чего хочу добиться.
Сайт на бутстрапе ковыряю.

Comment: А что вы попробовали сделать самостоятельно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Предложите вариант скролл-эффекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775780/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb-%d1%8d%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/805627/262779 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/729456/262779

Answer (score 0):

Первоисточники [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240028/css-make-a-background-image-scroll-slower-than-everything-else):

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".parallax").forEach(function(el,i) {
    var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset;
    var elBackgroundPos = "50% " + (windowYOffset * 0.02) + "px";

    el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgroundPos;
  });
};
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url('https://icdn4.digitaltrends.com/image/2019-dodge-challenger-rt-scat-pack-widebody-review-12-640x640.jpg');

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<p>In this example we have turned off parallax scrolling for mobile devices. It works as expected on all desktop screens sizes.</p>
<p>Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.</p>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>

<div class="parallax"></div>
```

Картинка взята рандомно.

[Здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/xourz3d9/) jsfiddle на всякий случай для примера.